# Multiple image upload to create thumbnail and store original, using filepicker

Tags: javascript, foreach, filepicker.io, filepicker

I am using `filepicker.js` library to store my images. User can upload a set of images using `filepicker.pickMultiple()` function. And I use the callback function to pick image urls and iterate through each url from the json response and use crop tool `filepicker.processImage()` to upload the cropped thumbnail.

```
filepicker.pickMultiple(
 function(urlList){
  var list="";
  var urlLength=urlList.length;
  var counter = 0;
  urlList.forEach(function (urlBlob,index) {
    filepicker.processImage(urlBlob.url,{},
      function(blob){
        counter++;
        list += "," +urlBlob.url + ";" + blob.url ;
        if(urlLength == counter ){alert(list)};
      } ,
      function(){
        counter++;
        list += "," +urlBlob.url + ";" + urlBlob.url ;
        if(urlLength == counter ){alert(list)};
      });
  });
});
```

The above code uploads multiple images properly and gives array of url information about the uploaded images. Then I iterate through each image url and use `filepicker.processImage()` to crop ech image .But the above code crops only the first image. Only one window appears for cropping image which has the first uploaded image. I would like to get my output as a list string which has this format `"originalImageUrl;croppedImageUrl"` .

Any help to figure out the issue?